# Induction proof to prove inequality?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

I'm quite comfortable proving by induction, but I've stumbled upon an exercise where you need to prove a inequality using induction, something I have never done before, and where I'm absolutely clueless how to start. It goes as follows:

The numbers $a_k$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$ is given by $a_0=1, a_1=2$ and $$a_k=5a_{k-1}-4a_{k-2}$$ for $$k\leqq2$$

Use proof by induction to prove $$a_{k-1}\leqq a_{k} \leqq 4a_{k-1}$$

If someone knows the answer it would be very much appreciated if you would share your wisdom :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do a proof by induction to show that $a_k = 4a_{k-1} - 2$ and then the proposition you have been asked to prove quickly falls out as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in most elementary cases, induction is always : base case, induction case. What are we trying to prove? That $a_{n} \leq a_{n+1} \leq 4a_n$ for all $n \geq 0$.

#### Base Case

The base case is to check that this is true for $n=0$. This gives $a_0 \leq a_1 \leq 4a_0$. This is true, since the inequality becomes $1 \leq 2 \leq 4$.

The base case is clear by checking that $1<2<4$.

#### Induction Case

For the induction case, we'll assume that $a_{k-1} \leq a_k \leq 4a_{k-1}$ holds true up till index $n$, and prove it for $n+1$. In fact, we only need to assume that $4a_{n-1} \leq a_n \leq 4a_{n-1}$.

Now, remember these simple facts, which we will be using (all variables below take values in the real numbers) :

1. If $y\geq z$ then for any $x$ we have $x+y > x+z$. (Hate $2$, so I'll skip it)
2. If $y \geq z$ and $x<0$ then $xy \leq xz$ (note the sign reverses)

That's what we need, these two facts.

---

We want to prove $a_{n+1} \geq a_{n}$ first. Remember that $a_{n+1} = 5a_{n} - 4a_{n-1}$. Now, from our induction hypothesis, we know that $a_n \geq a_{n-1}$. Multiply by $-4>0$ and use point $3$ to get $-4 a_n \leq -4a_{n-1}$. Now, add $5a_n$ to both sides, then use point $1$ to get $5a_n - 4a_n \leq 5_n - 4a_{n-1}$. The left hand side is $a_n$, the right hand side is $a_{n+1}$ so $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$.

---

Now let's prove that $a_{n+1} \leq 4a_n$. Once again, $a_{n+1} = 5a_{n} - 4a_{n-1}$. We know that $a_n \leq 4a_{n-1}$. Again, multiply by $-1$ and use point $3$ to get $-a_n \geq -4a_{n-1}$. Now, add $5a_{n}$ to both sides and use point $1$ to get $5a_n - a_n \geq 5a_n - 4a_{n-1}$. The left side is $4a_n$ , the right side is $a_{n+1}$ so $4a_n \geq a_{n+1}$.

---

Thus $a_n \leq a_{n+1} \leq 4a_n$ and the induction is complete!

Comment: Thank you for answering but how do you know this step $a_{n+1} \geq 5a_{n} - 4a_{n} = a_n$?

Comment: subtracting a larger quantity gives you a smaller number. i subtracted $4a_n$ instead of $4a_{n-1}$,which is a larger number, so the result is smaller.

Comment: But I'm assuming your doing this to the equation $a_{n+1}=5a_{n}-4a_{n-1}$, but if you then would want to substract , you would have to it to both sides of the equation not just one element of the equation. Srry I just trying to understand :-) @Teresa Lisbon (and thanks for replying btw)

Comment: I will edit the answer and make it more elaborate. Just give me a few minutes, i need to think over this in the bathtub (not),

Comment: thank you, your are very kind willing to help me.

Comment: @TheCreator Completed the edit, it is now far more elaborate and you can take a look!

Comment: Wow I totally understand now, thank you so much for your time!!!

Comment: @TheCreator You are welcome. In case you are interested, this question has been getting high attention on meta, and I suggest you read my answer. See if you 
 can connect with some of the points I put across, and tell me which helps you : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/why-do-high-rep-long-time-users-answer-duplicate-or-too-similar-questions-on-bo?cb=1 Thank you for the interaction.